# IzPack - variable from POM to be written in a target text file

Tags: file, variables, replace, pom.xml, izpack

My installer creates an application bundle for Mac manually as I did not find a better solution (but that is not the problem). In order to create such a bundle, I have a pre-prepared Info.plist file. My aim is to take a pom.version value from the installer's Maven POM file and write it to the Info.plist file. This is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<installation version="5.0">
    <info>
        <appname>MyApp</appname>
        <appversion>@pom.version@</appversion>
    </info>

    <resources>
        <res id="Info.plist" src="Info.plist" parse="yes" type="xml" />
    </resources>

    <!-- Panel definitions omitted for brevity -->

    <packs>
        <pack id="MyPack" name="MyApplicationPack"
            required="yes">
            <file targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/MyApp.app/Contents" src="Info.plist">
                <os family="mac" />
            </file>
            <parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist" />
        </pack>
    </packs>

</installation>
```

Firstly, the  should take the value from the POM using @pom.version@ . In the Info.plist file I use $APP_VER to fill in that value. Instead of the value such as 1.0-SNAPSHOT, I get the string: @pom.version@

The resource has parse="yes" attribute and also I added  tag for the file in the "pack" element.

The version of IzPack I use: 5.0.0-rc2.

Is there a way to make IzPack replace the version in the Info.plist file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an attribute in the parsable section, if you have placeholder set to @pom.version@ in Info.plist please use this:

```
<parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist" type="ant" />
```